How do I locate chat?
I'd like to participate in chat. I have only found the question and answer part. Is there a chat room for general conversation about LEGO? If so I can't seem to locate it and would like some help

Is there a chat room for general conversation about LEGO?
Click the top right icon on the menu bar then click the "chat" link:

It will take you a list of list of rooms about Bricks:

Click on the Bricks SE link.

Thank you. I look forward to conversing with fellow LEGO fans
